# Emergency brake light always on

Tags: honda, accord, parking-brake, brake-light

I got a 94 honda accord. Recently ebrake light on the dash shows up even the ebrake handle is down. I tried  to look at the switch on the ebrake and mess with it a little bit. Then the ebrake light comes off on the dash, but when I start pumping the pedal brakes it comes on again.  Is there any problem in the brake pedal switch? I tried turn off the car then turn it on again the ebrake light went off but when I  start pumping the brakes, it shows up again at the dash.  Brake fluid is at maximum level.

Comment: Your emergency brake should be on a different system than the brake pedal. Where is the switch for the light that you managed to turn off, and what engages it?

Comment: When I press the brake, there's a warning light on the dash saying brake lamp and (!) this signs appear even the ebrake is down.  Do you think there's a problem with the brake lights? Do I need to change the bulbs or the bulbs loosen?

Comment: Asking a question related to your problem because I have a problem that may be similar to yours. Does the master cylinder make a screeching noise if it is failing?

Comment: I've never heard a master cylinder make a screeching sound.  When they fail you'll normally find brake fluid leaking down the foot well inside the car behind the pedals.

Comment: Have you checked the tension on the emergency brake? it should click 4 or 5 times before engaging completely. Any more and it's useless. Any less, and it's probably always semi-engaged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the light was shut off after pumping the foot brakes the issue was not the parking brake. The problem is in the regular braking system you use to stop the car, as such it needs immediate attention. It may have been caused by something as simple as low brake fluid level. If the level is low either the system has a leak or the brake pads are worn to the point they should be replaced. If the fluid level is within the normal marks on the brake reservoir, the master cylinder may be failing. Many times in the early stages of master cylinder failure the brakes can be recovered by pumping the pedal. This will only work for so long before it catastrophically fails.